# During boot starting services and automatically stopping services

Tags: 14.04, boot

Im running Ubuntu 14.04. Im facing some weird issue, during boot it shows services starting but it also stopping the services automatically. And it stuck in any particular services like:

Stopping userspace bootsplash services.
OR
Stopping save udev log and update rules
etc...

And it never boot completely. Find the attached screenshot. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqu3S.png)

I tried package repair but it shows apt-get autoremove old kernels. (I didnt try this). But did package repair.

Anyone faced similar issue.